# Close queue tag bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, vote-to-close

I'm trying to participate in the "Burn the queue" squad and when I visit the C# tag link provided in this answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/223498/194126 (which is: https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=c%23&burn=1)

..I review a single C# question before it jumps to C (the filter is just `filter-tags=c`). It looks like it removes the URL encoded hash.

Not a big issue since I can just re-add the hash myself.. but thought it worth mentioning.

Comment: yeah, looks like problems with the `filter-tags`, it can't handle parameter with `#`, even if you put `#` back, it still shows the result from `c`

Comment: Workaround: Open the filter dialog and click Okay. That will make that the filter is applied correctly and stays applied.

Comment: looking into this

Comment: @rene That doesn't work for me. In fact.. even with C# in the filter.. pressing okay shows me plain old C.

Comment: Win 8, newest Chrome update.

Comment: I repro in IE11 as well. For c#-4.0 the workaround helped but in this case not...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was an issue with a 3rd party history plugin we use for the review pages.

A fix is on it's way out and will be with you in build rev `2014.2.28.2001` on meta and `2014.2.28.1410` on sites.

Comment: Awesome stuff. Thanks :) I need to get me a job with you guys.. all of the stuff you get to play with on this engine seems like heaps of fun.